# split the content of the file based on the delimiter not per line using awk, grep or sed

Tags: sed, split, grep

Assuming I have a file that contains this:

---

```
! 
Title1 
     Data1 
! 
Title2
    Data1
    Data2
    Data3 
! 
Title3
    Data1
    Data2
    Data3 
! 
end 
!
```

---

I want to split the contents of the file and use (!) punctuation mark as the delimiter.
Using awk I think is a bad idea because based on my observation it parses the file line by line, which is not what I need. Please help. Thanks

Comment: give maybe a sample of desired output because "split" could mean lot of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` works fine with `!` as separator.

```
awk -vRS="[!]" 'NR==3' file

Title2
    Data1
    Data2
    Data3
```

Here it prints record number `3` and as you see its not a single line.

Comment: It's interesting to note that record 3 is the one with `Title2` in it; there's an empty record before the first `!` in the data file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Since it start with a separator `!` `Title2` would be come record 3. So you get `<nothing>!Title1...!Title2...!Title3...`

Comment: hi @Jotne your example shows how to print a specific part of data, could you tell me how to print the output one by one? Thank you! :D

Comment: @srhsnl How do you like the output to be? You can do: `awk -vRS="[!]" '1'` to print all, or `awk -vRS="[!]" '{print NR ": " $0}'` to get record number.

Answer (score 1):

I think you stand a better chance with `awk` than with either `sed` or `grep`.  For example, if your data is in a file called `data`, then this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="!"} {print "[[" $0 "]]"}' data
```

produces:

```
[[]]
[[ 
Title1 
     Data1 
]]
[[ 
Title2
    Data1
    Data2
    Data3 
]]
[[ 
Title3
    Data1
    Data2
    Data3 
]]
[[ 
end 
]]
[[
]]
```

The only parts to quibble about are the empty record before the first delimiter and the record consisting of just a newline after the last delimiter.  It wouldn't be hard to eliminate those two records.